# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcce

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

My project builds just fine, but when I try to run it, it runs but I get this error on the debugger terminal. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcce;
```

build.gradle:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+'
```

Comment: I would suggest: 1. Include specific version of dependencies instead of using '+'.  2. Instead of using alpha versions, use stable ones.

Comment: The alphas came by default, I didn't add them, do you know the current versions?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your project `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
}
```

Comment: Version doesn't matter, I was saying make sure you add this in your project `build.gradle`